# The token of announce_peer in DHT

Tags: bittorrent, dht, kademlia

In http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0005.html, the announce_peer query needs a token which has the require ,"the "token" received in response to a previous get_peers query".

Does it mean that if node A has never send a get_peer query to node B, then node A would never receive a peer_announce query from node B ?

Answer (score 3):

> Does it mean that if node A has never send a get_peer query to node B, then node A would never receive a peer_announce query from node B ?

No, it's the other way around:

- Node A wants to *announce* that it is downloading a certain torrent.
- Node A makes a `get_peers` query to Node B.
- Node B sends a response to Node A for the `get_peers` query that it has just sent. Node B's response includes the `token`.
- Node A, now, can send an `announce_peer` query to Node B using the `token` it has just received from Node B's response.

Why all this fuss?

> The return value for a query for peers includes an opaque value known as the "token." For a node to announce that its controlling peer is downloading a torrent, it must present the token received from the same queried node in a recent query for peers. When a node attempts to "announce" a torrent, the queried node checks the token against the querying node's IP address. This is to prevent malicious hosts from signing up other hosts for torrents.
>
> http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0005.html

Comment: So because DHT uses UDP, and "announce" doesn't require a reply back, without the token, there is no way for the receiver to really know which ip the "announce" message came from, is this correct?

Comment: @redfish64 Yes that's my understanding, it basically guards against using a spoofed IP.

Answer (score 0):

The token represents a capability to announce that one is joining a swarm. It's like first you ask about the swarm -- "Hey, what's up with this swarm?" -- and the peer you ask tells you what it knows about that swarm, and it also gives you a ticket you can return, or not, if you want to join that swarm too. ***Fine-grained capability security for the win!***

Answer (score -1):

Yes that's right. It ensures that someone announcing a peer is actually interested in the corresponding torrent, and has demonstrated control over the announced address.